# How To Prevent Downloading Dependencies Of Maven In Docker

Tags: docker, maven, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to cache the maven dependencies of my project in GitHub Actions. I managed to cache my multi-layered Dockerfile but I couldn't manage to cache Maven dependencies. No matter what I do, those dependencies are being fetched on CI.

In my local, docker works as I expected. It caches dependencies very well.

## GitHub Actions

```
  - name: Setup Docker
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3


  - name: Build the Docker image
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
    with:
      labels: |
        ${{ steps.docker-metadata.outputs.labels }}
      tags: |
        ${{ env.ECR_DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG_URL || env.DOCKER_IMAGE_URL }}
      file: ${{ inputs.dockerfile-name }}
      context: .
      load: true
      cache-from: type=gha
      cache-to: type=gha
      build-args: |
        GITHUB_HEAD_REF="${{ github.head_ref }}"
        GITHUB_REF_NAME="${{ github.ref_name }}"
        GITHUB_RUN_ID="${{ github.run_id }}"
        GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER="${{ github.run_number }}"
        GITHUB_SHA="${{ github.sha }}"
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3-amazoncorretto-17 AS builder
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn -f pom.xml package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar target/*.jar extract

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine
COPY --from=builder dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/ ./
RUN wget -O dd-java-agent.jar "https://dtdg.co/latest-java-tracer"
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, Maven related stuff can be done on local or CI/CD runner and I will add the jar directly to dockerfile instead of doing all those actions inside it.

You can look at the dockerfile here as reference.

https://github.com/afsarkhan05/spring-projects/blob/main/spring-discovery/spring-discovery-service/Dockerfile